# Query building with this data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
╔════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║    WORK    ║
╠════╬══════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ a    ║ complete   ║
║  1 ║ a    ║ complete   ║
║  2 ║ b    ║ incomplete ║
║  3 ║ c    ║ complete   ║
║  4 ║ d    ║ incomplete ║
║  4 ║ d    ║ complete   ║
║  5 ║ e    ║ complete   ║
║  5 ║ e    ║ complete   ║
║  5 ║ e    ║ incomplete ║
║  6 ║ f    ║ incomplete ║
║  6 ║ f    ║ incomplete ║
╚════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

I want to build a query which retrieves only that id for which all homework is complete or a single incomplete

for example in above data i want to get only these id

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

not 6 because it has more than one incomplete work

Comment: Please add question to your post... And sample code with explanation of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662025/building-a-sql-query-with-this-data/14662061 and an answer is provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14662156/341117

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID, NAME
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN Work = 'Incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f93fd/7)

Comment: @JohnWoo I think it should be `COUNT(CASE WHEN Work = 'Incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 2`

Comment: @codingbiz count is different from sum. Consider this results: `1, 1, 0, 0`. In **sum** the result is `2`, while **count** returns `4`. `:D`

Comment: @codingbiz actually this is the same as `COUNT(CASE WHEN Work = 'Incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) < 2`

Comment: Yes... very correct. They achieve the same thing. That should have worked for SUM too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.ID
FROM Homework H
WHERE H.Work = 'Complete'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Homework H2 
        WHERE H2.Work != 'Complete' AND H2.ID = H.ID )
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1582d/1).

EDIT -- Actually, just noticed you also wanted those with a single incomplete -- let me edit.  That should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.ID
FROM Homework H
GROUP BY H.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 OR (
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Homework H2 
    WHERE H2.Work != 'Complete' 
      AND H2.ID = H.ID ))
```

And more fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7d43e/3

Good luck.

Comment: Completely agree -- been answering questions about EXISTS and was just in that mindset...